# E-Mail Signature

Tags: html, css

For the past two days I was trying to figure how `CodeTwo` software works in order to make a signature for the email.

I got to a point where I have the signature almost ready but with one problem.
I can't figure out how to vertically align an image (which is an icon) with the text. (because the software uses tables to align elements)
Basically, I have a `tr` with a `td` where I have this two elements that I want to center.
I attached a screenshot to show you what I mean by this. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

[image]

CODE Snippet: https://codepen.io/ovidiu1207/pen/xLerjy

Comment: Hi, please add a [mcve] to your question; we can't debug a screenshot!

Comment: Can you add the code used to create those elements?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED (forking from your codepen) => https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XawXEG

I was trying to "guess" the HTML based on your screenshot, so hopefully this solution works for you:

```css
.img { 
  margin-right: 6px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr>
    <td><img src="http://lorempixel.com/30/30" alt="banana" class="img">{Mobile}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try attribute `valign="top"` or css `style="vertical-align:top;"` or both to your `td` like given sample.

```
<td valign="top" style="vertical-align:top;"></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

`CodeTwo` seems to add a lot of useless code to the markup. I've tried playing with the elements and adding the property `vertical-align: middle;` to both the images seems to have worked.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WEWExX